# Mask/CLIP Raster images with different resolution in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I want to clip/mask raster image (500meters resolution) by another raster images (10 km resolution) using IDL Programming after the clip/mask process image should be in 500 meters resolution. I have 365 images pair and I want to a process by IDL programming. Can anybody write this code in IDL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: yes, somebody *could* write this code in IDL. Long answer: although most people here seem to like riddles and challenges, SO is not a coding service. why not try to write some code by yourself first?

Answer (score 0):

@MrFuppes

Initially, I write one code in IDL which able to mask/clip the same resolution images because those are in same dimension.
But I cannot write the mask function for different resolution where is the problem in dimension and resolution.

In my code:

Band 1(500 meters) is my base images and I want to mask this image by cloud mask image(500 meters)(It works well) and then I want to do another mask by AOD_MASK images(10 km) resolution.
But how to write MASK function for different dimension images I have no idea.
If you have any suggestion regarding this issue then, please suggested me.

Here I attached my test [DATA](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ezRwsOJg1t_MpljEddunv5eapnDwWsn1/view?usp=sharing) please check it.

Below is my IDL code:

```
 `Pro MASK

  COMPILE_OPT idl2
  ENVI, /RESTORE_BASE_SAVE_FILES
  ENVI_BATCH_INIT, /NO_STATUS_WINDOW
  print, '  ' + 'Batch Processing Start'
  print, '  ' + systime()

  ;******************************************************************************** 

  ;Input location of different file
  InputAOD = 'F:\DB_test_data\VAR2\TEST_DATA\Clip\'
  Input_cloud = 'F:\DB_test_data\VAR2\TEST_DATA\Clip\'
  Input_TOA_B1 = 'F:\DB_test_data\VAR2\TEST_DATA\Clip\'
  ;Output location
  Output = 'F:\DB_test_data\OUT_PUT\'

  ;  Search for inpiut data
  FileCloud = File_search(Input_cloud + "*Aerosol_Cldmask_Land_Ocean- 
  Aerosol_Cldmask_Land_Ocean.tif",COUNT=Count_in1)
  FileAOD = File_Search(InputAOD + '*Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land_2- 
  Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land.tif',COUNT=count_in)
  FileBAND1 = File_Search(Input_TOA_B1 + '*pssgrp_000501330352.EV_500_RefSB_1- 
  EV_500_RefSB.tif',COUNT=COUNT)

  nfiles = n_elements(count_in1)

    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    FOR k=0, nfiles-1 DO BEGIN
    Print, 'Processing File =', k +1
    Print, 'Total Files=', count_in1
    string_count = strtrim(nfiles,2)

    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    ;cloud(500_METER)
    ENVI_OPEN_FILE, FileCloud[k], r_FiD=FiD_cld
    IF (FiD_cld EQ -1) then return
    ENVI_FILE_QUERY, FiD_cld, dims=dims, nb=nb, ns=cld_ncols, nl=cld_nrows
    pos = [0]
    map_info = envi_get_map_info(FiD=FiD_cld)
    Cloud = Double(ENVI_GET_DATA(FiD=FiD_cld, dims=dims, pos=[0]))

    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    ;BAND_1(500_METER)
    envi_open_file,FileBAND1[k],r_fid=fid_T_B1
    if (fid_T_B1 eq -1)then return
    envi_file_query,fid_T_B1,dims=dims,nb=nb, ns=toa_B1_ncols, nl=toa_B1_nrows
    pos=[0]
    map_info1=envi_get_map_info(fid=fid_T_B1)
    layer1 = fltarr(toa_B1_ncols,toa_B1_nrows,nb)
    FOR i=0,nb-1 DO BEGIN
      layer1[*,*,i]=ENVI_GET_DATA(fid=fid_T_B1,dims=dims,pos=pos[i])
    ENDFOR
    ;To replace 65535 with NAN
    i=WHERE(layer1 eq 65535,count)
    if (count gt 0)then layer1[i]=!VALUES.F_NAN
    TOA_B1=layer1*0.000053811826d

    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    ;AOD(10KM_RESOLUTION)
    ENVI_OPEN_FILE, FileAOD[k], r_FiD=FiD_AOD
    IF (FiD_AOD EQ -1) then return
    ENVI_FILE_QUERY, FiD_AOD, dims=dims, nb=nb, ns=aod_ncols, nl=aod_nrows
    pos = [0]
    map_info = envi_get_map_info(FiD=FiD_AOD)
    layer2 = fltarr(aod_ncols,aod_nrows,nb)
    FOR i=0,nb-1 DO BEGIN
      layer2[*,*,i]=ENVI_GET_DATA(fid=FiD_AOD,dims=dims,pos=pos[i])
    ENDFOR
    ;To replace -9999 with NAN
    i=WHERE(layer2 eq -9999,count)
    if (count gt 0)then layer2[i]=!VALUES.F_NAN
    AOD=layer2*0.0010000000474974513d
    ;set the specific range for mask 
    AOD_MASK = 1.0*(AOD GE 0.0 and AOD LE 0.1) + (AOD GT 0.1)*0.0


    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

    ; to get same dimensions for B1TOA and CLD data
    if (cld_ncols le toa_B1_ncols) then begin
      xsize = cld_ncols
    endif else begin
      xsize = toa_B1_ncols
    endelse
    if (cld_nrows le toa_B1_nrows) then begin
      ysize = cld_nrows
    endif else begin
      ysize = toa_B1_nrows
    endelse

    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

    ; to call parameters again with same dims
    Cloud = FSC_Resize_Image(Cloud,xsize, ysize)
    Band1 = FSC_Resize_Image(TOA_B1,xsize, ysize)

    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    ;First masking processes with cloud mask images(500 meters)
    Cloud_masked = Cloud * Band1
    ;To replace 0 with NAN
    i=WHERE(Cloud_masked eq 0,count)
    if (count gt 0)then Cloud_masked[i]=!VALUES.F_NAN
    Cloud_masked_Band1=Cloud_masked
    ;Second masking processes with AOD_MASK images(10KM)




    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

    ;  Define output FileName
    FileName = STRJOIN(STRSPLIT(STRMID(FILE_BASENAME(FileBAND1[k], '.tif'), 0, 75), '.', /EXTRACT), '_')
    print, FileName
    ;  write output File 
    out_name_out = Output + FileName +'_masked_image.tif'
    map_info = envi_get_map_info(FiD=fid_T_B1)
    ENVI_WRITE_ENVI_FILE, Cloud_masked, out_name=out_name_out, map_info=map_info


    ;FileName = STRJOIN(STRSPLIT(STRMID(FILE_BASENAME(FileAOD[k], '.tif'), 0, 75), '.', /EXTRACT), '_')
    ;print, FileName
    ;  write output File
    ;out_name_out = Output + FileName +'_AOD.tif'
    ;map_info = envi_get_map_info(FiD=FiD_AOD)
    ;ENVI_WRITE_ENVI_FILE, AOD,out_name=out_name_out, map_info=map_info
    ;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$



    Print, FileName + ' ' + strtrim(k+1,2) + ' of ' + string_count + ' Processed'
  Endfor
  Print, '  ' + systime()
  Print, '  ' +  'Batch Processing End'
End
;$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
FUNCTION FSC_Resize_Image, image, cols, rows, $
  INTERPOLATE=interp, $
  MINUS_ONE=minus_one
  Compile_Opt idl2
  ;     Check parameters.
  IF N_Params() EQ 0 THEN BEGIN
    Print, 'USE SYNTAX: FSC_Resize_Image, image, cols, rows'
    RETURN, "FSC_Resize_Image Syntax Error"
  ENDIF
  ; Return to the caller on an error.
  On_Error, 2
  ;  Check image parameter for size. Only 2D and 3D images allowed.
  ndim = SIZE(image, /N_DIMENSIONS)
  dims = SIZE(image, /DIMENSIONS)
  IF ((ndim LT 2) OR (ndim GT 3)) THEN $
    Message, 'Input image must have two or three dimensions.'
  ;    Check for keywords. Default for minus_one is 0.
  interp = Keyword_Set(interp)
  IF N_Elements(minus_one) EQ 0 THEN minus_one = 0
  m1 = Keyword_Set(minus_one)
  ; 2D images are immediately passed to IDL's Congrid command, with
  ;  the CENTER keyword set.
  IF ndim EQ 2 THEN BEGIN
    RETURN, Congrid(image, cols, rows, CENTER=1, MINUS_ONE=minus_one, $
      INTERP=interp)
  ENDIF
  ;     24-bit images are handled differently. The "3" dimension of a 24-bit
  ;    image should not be interpolated.
  offset = 0.5 ; To center the pixel location (i.e., CENTER=1 for Congrid)
  index3 = Where(dims EQ 3)
  CASE index3 OF
    0: BEGIN
      srx = [0,1,2]
      sry = Float(dims[1] - m1) / (cols - m1) *(Findgen(cols) + offset) - offset
      srz = Float(dims[2] - m1) / (rows - m1) *(Findgen(rows) + offset) - offset
    END
    1: BEGIN
      srx = Float(dims[0] - m1) / (cols - m1) *(Findgen(cols) + offset) - offset
      sry = [0,1,2]
      srz = Float(dims[2] - m1) / (rows - m1) *(Findgen(rows) + offset) - offset
    END
    2: BEGIN
      srx = Float(dims[0] - m1) / (cols - m1) *(Findgen(cols) + offset) - offset
      sry = Float(dims[1] - m1) / (rows - m1) *(Findgen(rows) + offset) - offset
      srz = [0,1,2]
    END
  ENDCASE
  ;     Do the interpolation. Preserve nearest neighbor sampling, if required.
  IF interp THEN BEGIN
    RETURN, Interpolate(image, srx, sry, srz, /GRID)
  ENDIF ELSE BEGIN
    RETURN, Interpolate(image, Round(srx), Round(sry), Round(srz), /GRID)
  ENDELSE
 END`
```

Comment: I did not see this earlier. If you want me to get a notification, post a comment under mine with the @. Concerning the code, I'm not sure I see through this. So you're having greyscale and RGB (24bit) images, is that correct? And you want to map the RGB to the greyscale? Other than that, for the scaling issue the  `INTERPOLATE` function is fine I think.

Comment: @MrFuppes   Basically I have modis raster data in single raster band1(500 meters resolution) and I want to mask with first 500 metes resolution cloud mask image that is working fine in my code but when I try to use another mask function using 10 km resolution image, here I confuse to write this function. My output will be 500 meters of resolution.

Comment: Ok maybe I'll find some time today and have a look at the data you uploaded. The actual processing happens in `FSC_Resize_Image`, right?

Comment: @MrFuppes FSC_Resize_Image is required for the need to call all the images in the same dimension. It works when all raster images will be same dimension and resolution.
 In this code, I just simply multiply with cloud mask images(binary image, cloud = 0 & cloudless_area =1) and it works well.
But when we come to the next mask function, there is the problem is resolution and dimension. That's why I am confused about how to write this function in different resolution and dimension.

Comment: Ok so  you want to apply the 10x10km AOD data to 500x500m Band1 data? That seems like you not only need to adjust the resolution but also the spatial 'window'. Still need to have a look at the data...

Comment: @MrFuppes  YES. please look at this matter. How to solve this issue I am totally confused.

Comment: I must say I'm not an expert on satellite data. I checked the MODIS website and data and think this is more of a question on how to process the specific satellite products than a programming question. If I understand correctly, to apply AOD 10km data to Band1 500m data, you first need the find the corresponding pixel in AOD for each Band1 pixel. You will have to do this by comparing geolocations of the pixels in each dataset (use closest, define a limit how close it must be). Multiple 500m pixels will fall into one 10km pixel. Should be fine without interpolation.